# String & is not reflecting changes made But String does....while passing arguments?

Tags: c++, string, recursion, pass-by-reference

Question - Given a string a '0', '1' and '?'. Generate all possible strings where you can replace '?' with '0' or '1' ?

For eg - Input - "0??"
         Output - "000", "001", "010", "011".

I have written a simple program  for it -

```
void gen(string& str, int index)
{
    int i;
    if(str.length() == index)
    {
        cout << str << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=index; str[i]!='\0' && str[i]!='?';i++);

        if(str[i] == '?')
        {
            str[i] ='0';
            gen(str,i+1);
            str[i] ='1';
            gen(str,i+1);
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    string s ="0??";
    gen(s, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

It is not working correctly....
BUT IF YOU REPLACE THE ARGUMENT IN   void gen(String &, int) to

void gen(String, int)....

THEN IT WILL WORK CORRECTLY..

Can Anyone explain me please....

Comment: Does "generate" mean *printing* them to the console?  Or something like `std::vector<std::string>{ "000", "001", ... }` ?

Comment: You say "It is not working correctly"...  How can you tell?  What output *does* it produce?

Comment: the ouput in case of string reference is - "001" and "000"   which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the string *by reference*, there is a single string that is operated on by all of the recursive calls to `gen()` - instead of each call to `gen()` working on its own local copy.  Each recursive call to `gen()` modifies the (shared) string, removing all the '?' characters; when that call returns, there are no more '?' characters left to process so it simply terminates.

when you pass the string *by value*, each invocation of the `gen()` function gets its own local copy of the string; Any changes it makes to that string are thrown away and forgotten when the function returns to the previous level.  In this case your logic is correct.

(There was also a bug which caused it to crash on my Windows machine until I fixed it: `std::string` is not null-terminated, so rather than checking for `std[i] == '\0'` you should do something like `i < str.length()`.)

Comment: is there any way where we do not need to copy the strings and still get the correct answer.   like we pass only suffix of string as value....

Comment: There probably *is* a way to avoid copying the string.  My guess is that the logic would be more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

reference will maintain the value changed in the function call

```
after set str[1] ='0';

sub call: gen(str,2); will output combination: 000 001

reset str[1] ='1';

str is still 011

gen(str,i+1); output nothing
```

hope this piece of code can help

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
void gen(string& str, int index)
{
    int i;
    if(str.length() == index)
    {
        cout << str << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=index; str[i]!='\0' && str[i]!='?';i++);

        if(str[i] == '?')
        {
            printf("before set pos %d to 0: %s\n",i,str.c_str());
            str[i] ='0';
            printf("after set pos %d to 0: %s\n",i,str.c_str());
            gen(str,i+1);
            printf("before set pos %d to 1: %s\n",i,str.c_str());
            str[i] ='1';
            printf("after set pos %d to 1: %s\n",i,str.c_str());

            gen(str,i+1);
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    string s ="0??";
    gen(s, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

it outputs：

[image]

Comment: Your program doesn't work correctly for the simplest input `"000"` http://ideone.com/DZIgnB

Comment: @nodakai, i am trying to explain the reason, if you change  void gen(string& str, int index) to  void gen(string str, int index), the output is correct

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution will be:

As each '?' should be replaced with 0 and 1, we can see that there will be '2 ** (number of ?)' such possible replacement in the string. Eg., if we have three '?' in the string there will be 8 such possible replacement and if we consider their numeric value, they will be 0,1,2...,7 and binary representation of which will be 000,001,002,....,111.  Basically we should take the the numeric values and replace the '?'s with the bits from the numeric values.

Comment: Then he has to give up supporting more than 64 `?`'s in the input string!  (I'm joking, of course :)

Comment: Not exactly, we have  big numbers :) . But the point is, suppose we have 52 possible chars for each '?' and there are n such '?' on the string, there will be  52 ** n  possible output.